# Netlogo: Making a list from a GIS Vector Feature

Tags: gis, netlogo

I´m using Netlogo´s GIS extension. This is an attribute table of a SHP file viewed in QGis:

[image]

I want to take all the values of column SUBSECTOR to make this list: [Ch8 Ch9 M1 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 M15 M16 M17...Mn] , and pass it to a global variable called My-List with the following code:

```
to list-subsectors
 foreach gis:feature-list-of Subsectors-dataset [vector-feature ->
   set My-list gis:property-value vector-feature "SUBSECTOR"]
end
```

but `My-list` is only filled with only one value. How can all be listed? The Netlogo file can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gnvhqqcc5cmg66/Subsectors.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the functionalities from the GIS extension you can define the following auxiliary function:

```
to-report extract-column [column]
  report map [vector-feature -> gis:property-value vector-feature column ] (gis:feature-list-of Subsectors-dataset )
end
```

And then you can extract any column you want from your data file by writing something like:

```
set My-list extract-column "SUBSECTOR"
show My-list
```

I hope this works for you,
Fernando

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of testing this and no idea if it will work, but looking at your code, you are using `set` for the list (creating it new) instead of `lput` or `fput` (adding an item) as you iterate with the `foreach`. What happens with:

```
to list-subsectors
let My-list []
 foreach gis:feature-list-of Subsectors-dataset [vector-feature ->
   set My-list lput gis:property-value vector-feature "SUBSECTOR" My-list]
end
```

Comment: You are using the same name for a global and local variable, so it states an error. But nevertheless made the necessary changes but had the same result. I have edited the post by uploading the files if you want to try them. Thanks

Comment: I didn't realise that it was a global variable. But that doesn't change my answer - you need to have the `lput` in the code